# To Prove that $\ f(z)=cz^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> Let $f$ be a non-constant entire function satisfying the following conditions:
>
> - $f(0)=0$
> - For every positive real number $M$, the set $ \{z:|f(z)|<M\}$ is connected.
>
> Prove that $f(z)=cz^n$ for some constant $c$ and positive integer $n$.

My attempt:

Since $\ f$ is entire so zeros of $\ f$ are isolated so we can choose an $r>0$ such that $B_r=\{z:|z| \le r\}$ contains no zero of $\ f$ other than $0$. Now if I consider $m=\inf_{|z|=r} |f(z)|$ then the set $S=\{z:|f(z)|<m\}$ is connected (by 2nd condition) and also $S \cap B_r \ne \phi$ which implies $S \subset B_r $. Therefore, $\ f$ has only zero at $z=0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Now I think $\ f$ has a pole at $\infty$....which would imply it is a polynomial which has only zero at $z=0$...And this should imply that $\ f$ is of the desired form.

So I try to prove: $\lim_{|z| \to \infty}|f(z)|=\infty$

For this we have to show that for any $R>0$ there exists a $P>0$ such that $|f(z)| \ge R$ whenever $|z|>P$.

But from our previous discussion we can say that outside $B_r, ~ |f(z)| \ge m$.....So for any $R>m$ we can choose $P$ to be $r$. But what if $R \le m$..?

How can I prove that $\ f$ has a pole at $\infty $ ?

If I'm going wrong then please let me know...

Please help. Thank you..

Comment: If $f$ didn't have a pole at infinity, it would have an essential singularity there. Pick $\epsilon > 0$ and draw a circle of some radius $R$ such that $|f(z)| \ge \epsilon$ for all $z$ on this circle. Due to the singularity at infinity, the image of any neighborhood of $\infty$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$, and therefore there are points near $\infty$ with $|f(z)| < \epsilon$. Then $\{z : |f(z)| < \epsilon\}$ is disconnected by the circle of radius $R$.

Comment: Did you apply the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem to conclude the image of such nbd to be dense in C...?

Comment: Yes. I wrote an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded at infinity, then $f \equiv 0$. Otherwise, suppose $f$ had an essential singularity there. Choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that there exists a circle $S_R$ of radius $R$ around the origin on which $|f(z)| \ge \epsilon$ for all $z \in S_R$.

By any number of theorems (e.g. big Picard or Casorati-Weierstrass), the image of $\{z : |z| > R\}$ under $f$ contains points arbitrarily close to the origin. Therefore, $\{z : |f(z)| < \epsilon\}$ contains both $0$ and a point outside $S_R$, which contradicts connectivity.

Hence, $f$ must have a pole at infinity, so it's a polynomial. The only zero is at the origin, so $f$ is a multiple of $z^n$.

Comment: Nice argument..Thank you..

Comment: You're very welcome.